# Homomorphism from $D_n$ to $D_{\infty}$

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, dihedral-groups

I was wondering why for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there's a homomorphism that is surjective from $D_{\infty}$ to $D_n$?

What is the intuition for that?

Thank you.

Comment: Given any two groups $G,H$ there is always a homomorphism $G\to H$. So you  must have something special in mind, can you tell us which homomorphism you have in mind?

Comment: Is it like $C_n=\{\exp(2\pi ik/n)\}$ in $S_1=\{z\in\mathbb C: |z|=1\}$?

Comment: @ancientmathematician Whoops. I meant surjective homomorphism.

Comment: Did you mean injective where you wrote surjective?  How could you have a surjective map from a finite group to an infinite one?

Comment: You have now changed the question so much that it's a duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3573119/surjective-homomorphism-from-the-infinite-dihedral-group-to-each-finite-dihedral?rq=1

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I meant surjective, but I've edited the problematic part :)

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thank you! apparently this is the reason I didn't find anything...